# Splitting At An Index Greater Than The Size Of A Vector

Tags: scala

Why **doesn't** this expression throw an index out of bound exception?

```
scala> Vector(1,2,3,4).splitAt(50000000)
res2: (Vector(1, 2, 3, 4),Vector())
```

Answer (score 2):

From the scaladoc of `splitAt`:

```
/** Splits this $coll into two at a given position.
  *  Note: `c splitAt n` is equivalent to (but possibly more efficient than)
  *         `(c take n, c drop n)`.
  *  $orderDependent
  *
  *  @param n the position at which to split.
  *  @return  a pair of ${coll}s consisting of the first `n`
  *           elements of this $coll, and the other elements.
  */
def splitAt(n: Int): (Repr, Repr)
```

Scaladoc for `drop`:

```
/** Selects all elements except first ''n'' ones.
  *  $orderDependent
  *  @param  n    the number of elements to drop from this $coll.
  *  @return a $coll consisting of all elements of this $coll except the first `n` ones, or else the
  *          empty $coll, if this $coll has less than `n` elements.
  */
def drop(n: Int): Repr
```

And for `take`:

```
/** Selects first ''n'' elements.
  *  $orderDependent
  *  @param  n    the number of elements to take from this $coll.
  *  @return a $coll consisting only of the first `n` elements of this $coll,
  *          or else the whole $coll, if it has less than `n` elements.
  */
def take(n: Int): Repr
```

As you can see, these methods are designed not to throw any exceptions.

Comment: It looks strange not to throw an exception, by Java standards, but for some reason, I prefer it this way.

Comment: The only reason I can think of for not throwing is that they want to preserve some sense of referential transparency and hence purity of the functions.

Comment: @I.K. it's more "scala" way to avoid throwing exceptions for "ordinary" situations. You usually replace throwing exception with wrapping result in `Option` or `Either`. In the case of `splitAt` it's possible to return reasonable results for any arguments without changing or wrapping result type.

Comment: @I.K. - The principle of most high-order collections methods is to do the best job possible and not mix error-checking of not-strictly-needed details with your application logic.  Most of the time, if you do the most sensible thing possible, the whole thing works out without ever having to worry about bounds issues.  Since the library does it for you, by being sensible, a whole class of annoying errors vanishes.  (The class that appears instead, which is it really mattering that the collection is that big even though you don't use it, is tiny in comparison.)

Comment: @RexKerr, yes sensibility does come into but as you know in real world programming lapses do happen. It smacks of inconsistency though. Consider this: `val v = Vector(1,2,3,4)` and then `v(4)` and the result is `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 4`. Why do that in one case but not others?

Comment: @I.K. - What value can you return for `v(4)` that makes it clear that there was actually no element there?  (In the case of `splitAt`, what actually happened is clear from the result because the first collection doesn't have as many elements as you asked for, and the second is empty.)